# How to redirect using htaccess and regex the middle part of URLs leaving the dynamic end as is?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect a lot of URLs by changing just some part that is in the middle or at the end of the URL. If that part is in the middle, the end must stay the same.

I need to accomplish this by using **htaccess and regex**.

I found a lot of examples online, but most of the are one on one redirection, and not covering enough dynamic websites. Also I haven't found answer to this in other questions here.

I have URL:

`www.domain.com/something` (alone)  OR URLS like

`www.domain.com/something-aaa-bbb-ccc` OR only

`www.domain.com/something-aaa`

How to make it:

`www.domain.com/somethingELSE` but ALSO:

`www.domain.com/somethingELSE-aaa-bbb-ccc`

(KEEP aaa-bbb or whatever goes at the end the same)

---

**To make this more human readable**, let's say these are shops with a lot of locations:

`www.domain.com/my-shop` - Without anything else after OR:

`www.domain.com/my-shop-belgrade`  ... or

`www.domain.com/my-shop-new-york` ... or  ... `shop-wherever-wherever-wherever`

TO BE:

`www.domain.com/my-office` - Without anything else after OR:

`www.domain.com/my-office-belgrade`  ... or

`www.domain.com/my-office-new-york` ... or  ... `my-office-wherever-wherever-wherever`

---

The following was my urgent solution, but it's not dynamic, and it only covers 2 examples, but I need solution for the dynamic website, the solution that covers all the above.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    Redirect 301 /my-shop /my-office
    Redirect 301 /my-shop-new-york /my-office-new-york 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: So you just want to replace the leading /my-shop with /my-office and leave everything afterwards as it is?

Comment: @DusanBajic Yes, exactly

Comment: `RedirectMatch 301 /my-shop(.*) /my-office$1`

Comment: `Redirect /my-shop/ /my-office/` should work. The pattern of `Redirect` directive is dynamic and it will match anything after `/my-shop/` and append it to the end of the target path `/my-office/`

Comment: @DusanBajic 
`RedirectMatch 301 /my-shop(.*) /my-office$1` – Dusan Bajic "
This works like a charm!!! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @MirjanaKatalina you can write an answer to your own question, so people who have a similar problem won't need to go through the comments looking for it. [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that worked out for me.

In order to replace the leading `/my-shop` with `/my-office` and leave everything afterwards as is, I used a capturing group:

```
(.*)
```

and replaced it with `$1`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /my-shop(.*) /my-office$1
```